# Php does not show the lowest value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to see the highest and lowest Value using php. But it show the max value 9.
It looks like the [image: picture]

My php code is here.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("simple",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT* FROM simple_tb ";

 $query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        $id = array($row['id']);
        $id = array_filter($id);
        $min = min($id);
        $max = max($id);

{
 echo "Max Value: ".$max."<br> Min Value : ".$min;
 }
 ?>
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G3tJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a table with the data ?

Comment: You are calling `min()` and `max()` on an array with 1 element (`$id`).

Comment: The structure of this code is very strange to me, and I suspect that's the cause of the problem.  What's actually the loop body here?  It looks like *only* the line `$id = array($row['id']);` is actually in the loop.  And you're creating a new array with every iteration of the loop, so it'll only ever have one element in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your `array` up, then call `min` and `max` on it. Easiest way is to instantiate the `array` before the `while` statement, and use the `[]` syntax to add an element to the `array` like shown below. Also a note is that brackets are a nicer way to instantiate `arrays`, then the old `array()` version.

```
$ids = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        $ids[] = $row['id'];

$min = min($ids);
$max = max($ids);
```

Comment: or `SELECT MAX(id),MIN(id) FROM simple_tb`

Comment: Yes, but seing the scope of the question, it's probaly better to learn proper array management than solve it by sql. Preferably in real world scenario the sql solution should always be chosen.

Comment: If it solved the question, please accept the answer as the correct one :)